# How to change color of arrow in TextField Select from material-ui

Tags: css, select, overriding, material-ui

I have a problem with changing color of my arrow icon in **Material-ui TextField Select**.

I give props:

```
icon: {
    fill: "white !important",
  },
```

But the color doesn't change.
I've tried probably everything I've found on the internet. 
Input props with icon doesn't work.

```
<TextField
          id="outlined-select-currency"
          select
          label={label}
          name={this.props.name}
          className={classNames(this.props.classes.textField)}
          onChange={(e) => this.props.handleChange(e)}
          value={this.props.value}
          SelectProps={{
            MenuProps: {
              className: this.props.classes.menu,
              icon: "white !important"
            }
          }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            classes: {
              root: this.props.overrideCssLabel,
              focused: this.props.overrideCssFocusLabel,
              icon: {
                color: "white !important"
              }
            },
          }}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
              root: this.props.overrideCssInputRoot,
              focused: this.props.overrideCssInputFocus,
              notchedOutline: this.props.overrideCssInputNotchedOutline,
              icon: this.props.icon
            },
            style: {
              color: this.props.color
            },
          }}
          margin="normal"
          variant="outlined"
        >
          {selectList.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be solved by using the `classes` part of `SelectProps` and passing them like so:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

type Props = {
  someProps: any
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  icon: {
    color: 'white',
  },
});

const CustomTextInput: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  ...someProps
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TextField
      {...someProps}
      select
      SelectProps={{
        classes: { icon: classes.icon },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomTextInput;
```

See https://material-ui.com/api/select/ for a list of `SelectProps` and https://material-ui.com/api/select/#css for a list of CSS class names for `classes`

Answer (score 1):

Add this into `sx` prop also works:

```
'& .MuiSvgIcon-root': {
    color: 'white',
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextField
  select
  fullWidth
  label={t(Translation.PAGE_INPUT_RESULTS_TEST_MEASUREMENT_LIST_FIELD_NAME_RESULT)}
  sx={{
       "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
            color: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.main
        }
                  }}
                >
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the ways finally i overright using style. it's css style so it's overright even you can use !important to (im not sure with color variable).

```
<HeartIcon color="primary" style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.main }} />
```

Here this is how i used icon in Textfield

```
<TextField
 placeholder="Type your message"
 endAdornment={(
  <InputAdornment position="end">
     <Box className="d-flex align-items-center">
     <IconButton
                      onClick={() => {
                        console.log('attachment..');
                      }}
                      sx={{ mr: -1.25 }}
                    >
                      <AttachIcon style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.main }} />
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton onClick={() => {
                      console.log('sent..');
                    }}
                    >
                      <HeartIcon color="primary" style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.main }} />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Box>
                </InputAdornment>
                )}
            />
```

Answer (score -3):

Just remove the quotes.

```
icon: {
    fill: white !important
  }
```

Comment: This is incorrect since the `icon` prop provided is a JS object, not a normal CSS class.